# How can I change the border style of a Tab Control?

Tags: c++, winapi, atl, wtl

This is the tab control I am currently using in my dialog:
[image]

However, the border style at the bottom and the right border is really annoying me. I would like to have the same style as on the left/top border.

I can't seem to find any settings or documentation on an option or style flag which would allow me to do this.

I would really like to find a way to solve this without using a custom, ownerdrawn tab control.

Do you have any information which could lead me towards solving this problem?

Comment: [Enabling Visual Styles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773175.aspx).

Comment: Visual Styles is actually a good idea. That kinda solved the issue, but I'd still be interested in a solution without VS

Comment: The link contains steps that don't require you to use Visual Studio. Although it's debatable why you wouldn't want to use Visual Studio for Windows development. There isn't much of an alternative around.

Comment: I was refering to Visual Styles with VS. Yeah, there isn't, but I just don't like to just get around problems without actually knowing the internals or a proper solution

Comment: Visual Styles have nothing to do with VS. They have to do with the *ComCtl32.dll* and *User32.dll* libraries.

Comment: Not applying Visual Styles **is** the problem, and applying Visual Styles is the proper solution. If you don't manifest your application to use Visual Styles, controls are rendered using the old, un-themed look. If you do want to use the old, un-themed look, but modify the right and bottom border only, there is no easy way to implement this.

Comment: Your other option is to make your own tab controls, which should be easy as tab controls are not intended to host other controls, but rather appear behind tab pages (which should be dialog controls that are siblings of the tab control itself) and trigger hiding and showing of pages, so as to give the illusion of hosting controls. Of course, if you go down this route, you will have to recreate all the tab control's event handling behavior precisely, including keyboard events, in order to maintain consistency.

Comment: Visual Styles comes as part of Common Controls 6, which has better custom drawing support. I don't know if this applies to tab controls or not, but if it does, then you can just skin the tab control as you wish and it will still behave properly.